# Error in detecting objects using the svm algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, dlib

I have a program in Python that uses the Dlib library 19.10, the classifier uses an xml file to do the learning of the images and then I execute the following code that creates a .svm file for classification:

```
import dlib

opcoes = dlib.simple_object_detector_training_options()
opcoes.add_left_right_image_flips = True
opcoes.C = 5

dlib.train_simple_object_detector("recursos/treinamento_casas.xml", "recursos/detector_casas.svm",opcoes)
```

The first problem happens on line 4 (`opcoes.add_left_right_image_flips = True`), when False is placed there is no error, training normally occurs, however when I put True the following error appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/marco/Desktop/Projeto_de_pesquisa/treinamento_casas.py", line 7, in dlib.train_simple_object_detector("recursos/treinamento_casas.xml", "recursos/detector_casas.svm",opcoes)
>
> RuntimeError: An impossible set of object labels was detected. This is happening because none of the object locations checked by the supplied image scanner is a close enough match to one of the truth boxes in your training dataset. To resolve this you need to either lower the match_eps, adjust the settings of the image scanner so that it is capable of hitting this truth box, or adjust the offending truth rectangle so it can be matched by the current image scanner. Also, if you are using the scan_fhog_pyramid object then you could try using a finer image pyramid. Additionally, the scan_fhog_pyramid scans a fixed aspect ratio box across the image when it searches for objects. So if you are getting this error and you are using the scan_fhog_pyramid, it's very likely the problem is that your training dataset contains truth rectangles of widely varying aspect ratios. The solution is to make sure your training boxes all have about the same aspect ratio.
>
> image index 23 
>   match_eps: 0.5 
>   best possible match: 0.496824 
>   truth rect: [(508, 482) (600, 650)] 
>   truth rect width/height: 0.550296 
>   truth rect area: 15717 
>   nearest detection template rect: [(492, 515) (595, 618)] 
>   nearest detection template rect width/height: 1 
>   nearest detection template rect area: 10816

The second problem occurs in the detection of objects in the images, the algorithm does not recognize any objects in the test images, not even the images that were used for training, the algorithm must draw a rectangle on the detected objects and this does not happen. Code snippet:

```
contador = 0
detectorCasa = dlib.simple_object_detector("recursos/detector_casas.svm")
for imagem in glob.glob(os.path.join("imagens/teste", "*.jpg")):
    img = cv2.imread(imagem)
    objetosDetectados = detectorCasa(img)
    for d in objetosDetectados:
        e, t, d, b = (int(d.left()), int(d.top()), int(d.right()), int(d.bottom()))
        cv2.rectangle(img, (e,t), (d, b), (0,0,255), 2)
        contador += 1

    cv2.imshow("Detector de casas", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Would the error be in the xml file?

**I have no idea of ​​the problem that is occurring and also find nothing on the internet**

**Sample data**

https://github.com/MarcosPauloSR/questionStackOverflow

Comment: please give us your sample data to work on. thanks.

Comment: I inserted the access link to my GitHub

Comment: Can you help me?